# php Rest API get element

Tags: php, angular, rest, api, backend

I'm trying to get values from a database and print them out in my angular 2 webbapplikation. The problem I'm having is that I can print out the correct values in php echo, but I wan't to get each of this value and put them in a list in angular.

The question is, how can I retrieve only the names?
The server response at the moment, printed in the console.

```
Response {_body: "{"users":[{"name":"Jan"},{"name":"Pelle"},{"name":"Sara"},{"name":"c"},{"name":"21321"}]}"
```

php rest API code

```
$user = new User($dbh);
$stmt = $user->read();
$tableRows = $stmt->rowCount();
if($tableRows>0){

    $users_arr=array();
    $users_arr["users"]=array();

    $result = $stmt -> fetchAll();
    foreach($result as $row){
        $user_item=array(
            "name" => $row['username']
        );
        array_push($users_arr["users"], $user_item);
    }
    echo json_encode($users_arr);
    //return $users_arr;

}else{
    echo json_encode(
        array("message" => "No users found")
    );
}
```

Angular 2 frontend code

```
this.http.get('http://localhost/shareVideoAppPHP/read.php', {headers: this.headers})
        .subscribe((message) => { //Function data
            console.log("from server", message);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log("Error from server!", error);
        });
```

Comment: PHP which framework ?

Comment: `$users_array = array();
 foreach($result as $row){
  $users_array[] = $row['username'];
 }`

This should make only the names appear as an array, not sure what exactly you mean with "how can I retrieve only the names". Could you post an example array?

Comment: Not really using any framework, just making a simple backend rest API

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with the map function provided by angular

```
            const response = JSON.parse(message.text());
            const names = response.users.map((user) => user.name);
            console.log('names' + names);
```